# Responsive desing on iPhone / Page is too wide

Tags: html, ios, css, iphone, responsive-design

I am working on this project: http://www.ing-czech.cz/ If I open this page on iPhone, the page is too wide and small. I used 
  `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`

Thank you for your ideas.

Lukas

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you insert the relevant code in your question please? It's best to avoid external links and questions that are solely based on external content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked to your code and found these CSS declarations :

```
#footer {
    width: 940px;
}

/* ... */

#wrapper {
    min-width: 1000px;
}

/* ... */

#bunka {
  min-width: 800px;
}
```

The iPhone screen is too small to render these elements, so Safari zooms out your page to show your page.

Comment: Thank you very much, removing the min-width parameters helps.